# chrome extension chome.tabs.onUpdate running twice?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

```
//In background.js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabid, info, tab) {
    console.log(info);
});
```

I'm try to set it up so onUpdate runs once every time a youtube video page loads. I want wait for load after a youtube video loads. When I load directly from a url I get what I expect, but when I navigate to a suggested video, there are 2 loading/complete cycles. One for the current video, One for the next video.

[image: Direct Url]

This is the output for a direct url youtube video.

[image: Navigating]

This is what happens if I navigate to a youtube video while watching another youtube video.

In my manifest I have a simple background.js script, permission for webNaviagtion and Tabs.

I don't know why it's running twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tabs.onUpdated` is invoked for each `frame`/`iframe`, the Youtube watch page loads one.

[`webNavigation API`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation) provides `frameId` to the event listeners, the main page has `frameId == 0`.

Note that Youtube doesn't reload the page when the user goes from one video to another or from the main Youtube page to a video page so to detect these changes you may use `chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated` event listener or a content script that will listen to the DOM events used by the site, namely ["spfdone"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32277150/3959875).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just tried onHistoryStateUpdate and I'm still getting it firing twice, both logs have a frameId of 0 as well.

Comment: Which means that the history state was updated twice by the page.

Comment: Ah okay, I guess my question now would be how do I set it up so it only runs on the page I'm going to. It runs for the current youtube url and then next url. 
http://imgur.com/lcKjZc6

Comment: Well you can check the tab's current url with `chrome.tabs.get(details.tabId, ....)` - if both are equal then it's the new page url or use some other way.

Comment: Or. Youtube use history.pushState API. and chrome.tabs.onUpdate doesn't handle it yet. See http://crbug.com/465709