# chrome extension content script not working as expected

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a new Chrome Extension. And I have a `content.js` file that looks like:

```
console.log('here');
```

I have a `manifest.json` file that looks like:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Netflix Binge Enabler",
  "version": "0.1",
  "permissions": [
    "webNavigation"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["eventPage.js"],
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "http://www.netflix.com/*"
      ],
      "js": ["jquery-2.1.3.min.js", "content.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

`eventPage.js:`

```
console.log('here2');
chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener(function (details) {
  console.log('Page uses History API');
});
```

When I go the `netflix.com` I get the appropriate `'here'` string to show up in the console, but once I navigate to a movie/TV show, I don't get a second `'here'` even though the URL changes.

UPDATED: When I try to add a listener to the `onHistoryStateUpdated` event, nothing triggers when I change pages. The initial `console.log('here2')` doesn't fire at all so it seems like the background page isn't working properly. Might need to send an event from the content.js page or something?

Thanks!

Comment: For starters, 1) background page: see the docs for `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` or `chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated` 2) content script only: find and use the DOM event netflix triggers to signal the page transition like shown in ["spfdone" on youtube](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32277150/3959875). I'll add a more complete answer later unless there's a better one or a duplicate one.

Comment: @wOxxOm a netflix complete answer would help greatly for me, thanks.

Comment: @wOxxOm I tried to add a listener to `onHistoryStateUpdated` like in the link Xan posted, but couldn't get it to trigger properly. I'll update my question with what I've tried.

Comment: @wOxxOm in that answer, the content script code is YouTube specific (looks at the red progress bar at the top of the screen to trigger events). I can't seem to find something similar about Netflix that I could listen to

Comment: @ShailPatel, [Where to read console messages from background.js in a Chrome extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10258029)

Comment: @wOxxOm aha thank you!