# Google Chrome content_script not loading JS on matching URL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

Even after searching a lot of topics in stack overflow, nothing helped me to fix this error...

I'm trying to create an extension, and for now there are simple codes in it, but unfortunately, the console is not logging 'Hello, world!' from the content_scripts file.

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Example",
    "shortname": "exmpl",
    "description": "__MSG_appDesc__",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "default_locale": "en",
    "author": "Mateus Akino",
    "icons": {
        "16": "i16x.png",
        "48": "i48x.png",
        "128": "i128x.png"
     },
    "homepage_url": "http://example.com/",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "i32x.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "update_url": "http://example.com/update.xml",
    "chrome_url_overrides": {
        "newtab": "newtab.html"
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["*://*.youtube.com/*"],
        "js": ["execute.js"],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    }],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "permissions": [
   "activeTab", "tabs", "i18n", "management", "webNavigation", "<all_urls>"
   ]
}
```

**execute.js**

```
console.log("Hello, world!");
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener(function (details) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        file: "execute.js"
    });
});
```

Comment: I think [`spfdone` event](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32277150/) is a better solution because it doesn't require the background page at all.

Comment: Which page are you testing on and can you ensure `chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener` is called?

Comment: @HaibaraAi I added 'console.log("Test");" to it, and no, it doesn't seem to be called.

Comment: Please describe the *exact* URL and the *exact* user interaction with the browser UI which you are performing. Describe *exactly* what you are seeing in the [various appropriate consoles for your extension](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38920982/3773011) and describe *exactly* what you expect to see. Also, please tell us what you are attempting to accomplish.  Right now, all we know is that you are not seeing  'Hello, world!' at some point when you are expecting it, but not when that is.  Your code implies that you expect to see it at other times, in addition to when you first load a page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem, so I'm posting it here if someone else has the same issue.

Looks like the code was fine, the problem was the way I was loading the extension...
As I'm using '**Load unpacked extension**', my `manifest.json` wasn't updating just by disabling and enabling it (neither by using **Refresh extensions now**).

So I removed the extension, loaded it again and it's working normally now.

Comment: The manifest of an unpacked extension is reloaded when you *click* `Reload (Ctrl-R)` using a mouse.